# When can I ask questions again

Tags: support, asking-questions

Sorry to be a pain, I have a couple of burning questions I'd like to ask (to my pleasant surprise since I've been blocked asking for exceeding the limit I've found I don't need to really ask so many if I spend more time doing research which is the whole point I guess), could someone let me know how long I have to wait until I can ask again?  How many more days?

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 7):

This is simply a **rolling window of 30 days**. So, once you extend past 30 days from your 50th most recent question, then you'll be able to ask a new question. Then, of course, you'll be blocked again until the next rollover.

As such, my original prediction was that you'd be able to post today, as this would be [30 days from your 50th most recent question on your profile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5565323/problem-with-asp-net-url). However, as you've noticed, this isn't the case, and the reason is because **deleted and closed questions are taken into account for the rolling count**.

After inquiring with the helpful [Rebecca Chernoff](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/140548/rebecca-chernoff) I was informed that you actually have 7 deleted questions in your *real* 50 most recent questions. This would put your next question date to *no later than May 11th, 2011*. Your 43rd most recent question was [on April 11th, 2011](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5620124/simple-web-control-isnt-rendering-properly), so combinations of deleted question timestamps can only put your 50th most recent as earlier than that, not possibly later.

Comment: Ah thanks didn't think of working it out like that!

Comment: @Tom Well, let's see if my guess was right. Are you able to ask (a single) question now? ♪

Comment: nope :(.

Comment: @Tom I had a hunch based on your lack of result, and made some inquiries on it. See my update for that. ♪

Comment: thank you for looking into it for me!  May 11th?  That sucks though!  :-(  I wish there was more warning for this it feels like I've done something terribly wrong.  All those deleted q's were self deleted not deleted by anyone else